# Is there somone help me to show that :$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}i^k.((sin(-i))^{k})\pi$ is always real?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, proof-verification

I performed some calculations in wolfram alpha for some values of $k$.

I found that many values of the following series are real:

$\sum_{k=0}^{n}i^k  \sin^k(-i) \pi$

Note: $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Could someone help me prove that this sum's values are real for all $n$?

Comment: Note that since $i\sin(-i)=\sinh(1)\gt1$, the infinite series in the title diverges.

Answer (score 2):

$$S_n=\pi\sum_{k=0}^n i^k\sin^k(-i)=\pi\sum_{k=0}^n i^k(-i\sinh 1)^k=\pi\sum_{k=0}^n \sinh^k 1=\text{Some real number}$$

Comment: Thank you , sorry for my bad question .

Comment: @zeraouliarafik There is nothing bad about your question.

Comment: @does is it the same for cos or it will gave complex values ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik $\cos(-i)=\cosh 1$. Can you take it from there?
$$$$
$$$$
(The answer is no, but try to prove it :))

Comment: it's seems had a complex values

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sin -i=-i\sinh 1$.
Now, if $k$ is even, then $i^k$ and $(-i \sinh 1)^k$ is always real.
If $k$ is odd, then $i^k$ is pure imaginary and $(-i\sinh 1)$ is also pure imaginary. The product of 2 imaginary numbers makes a real number.
Therefore the sum is always real, no matter what $n$ is.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) it can be shown that,

$$
i \sin{\theta} = \frac{1}{2}\left(e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}\right).
$$

When you set $\theta$ equal to $-i$, then you obtain,

$$
i \sin{-i} = \frac{1}{2}\left(e - e^{-1}\right),
$$

which is a real number.

Multiplying a real number by a real number yields a real number, thus raising it to an integer power will also yield a real number. Adding real numbers together will also always yield a real number. It would therefore be strange if you would obtain a complex number.